# Is it possible to display a 3d object outside a Plane, and without a tap?

Tags: android, ocr, arcore, plane, 3d-model

I'm developing an android app capable of recognizing texts (doing it with Google Vision).

My goal is to wrap the text recognized with an AR (I'm using ARcore) rectangle as soon as it corresponds to a char sequence.
The problem I'm facing is that the text I want to recognize is on a small piece of metal.
It makes it impossible to detect a Plane on it ---> impossible to place the 3D rectangle.

I was wondering if with the coordinates I get from the text detected (I get either the 4 corner points or `getboundingbox()`) it is possible to create a custom Plane on the metal item in order to display my rectangle.

I've already tried different ways of doing it, and I can't do it.

```
ArFragment fragment;

 Session session = fragment.getArSceneView().getSession();
                float[] pos = {0, 0, -1};
                float[] rotation = {0, 0, 0, 1};
                Anchor anchor = session.createAnchor(new Pose(pos, rotation));
                placeObject(fragment, anchor, Uri.parse("model.sfb"));


private void placeObject(ArFragment arFragment, Anchor anchor, Uri uri) {
        ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(arFragment.getContext(), uri)
                .build()
                .thenAccept(modelRenderable -> addNodeToScene(arFragment, anchor, modelRenderable))
                .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                            Toast.makeText(arFragment.getContext(), "Error:" + throwable.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return null;
                        }
                );
    }


private void addNodeToScene(ArFragment arFragment, Anchor anchor, ModelRenderable renderable) {
        AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
        TransformableNode node = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());
        node.setRenderable(renderable);
        node.setParent(anchorNode);
        arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene().addChild(anchorNode);
        node.select();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe ARCore will let you access the feature points that it tracks (for example, if using Unreal, see https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/unreal/arcore/blueprint/Get_All_Trackable_Points).  You could search for feature points tracked by ARCore within the area of the image defined by the coordinates you get from the detected text.  I believe you can get the pose of tracked points, but I'm not sure if the orientation piece of the pose would have a high confidence without sufficient feature points to infer existence of a plane.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I try to do your answer, but I wasn't able to get an efficient Pose able to help me display my 3d model.

Comment: At the end, i abandonned the ARCore way, and I did a simple Rectangle wrapping the text, and displaying  the text detected over it.